# CakePHP send email

Tags: php, email, cakephp

I've got a problem with sending mail using CakePHP. Everythings giong well, but i didn't receive any single mail , i tired to send to 2 different emails .

//WebsitesController.php

```
App::uses('AppController','Controller');
App::uses('CakeEmail','Network/Email');
class WebsitesController extends AppController
{
    public $helpers = array('Html','Form','Session');
    public $components = array('Email','Session');

public function contact()
{

    $this->set('dane',  $this->Website->findById(4));        
}
public function contact_email()
{ /* all data is taken from contact.ctp, I debuged all data below and it's correct */
    $useremail = $this->data['Website']['useremail'];
    $usertopic = $this->data['Website']['usertopic'];
    $usermessage = $this->data['Website']['usermessage'];
    $Email = new CakeEmail();
    $Email->from(array($useremail => ' My Site'));
    $Email->to('wigan@mail.com');
    $Email->subject($usertopic); // all data is correct i checked several times
    $Email->send($usermessage);
    if($Email->send($usermessage))
    {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Mail sent','default',array('class'=>'alert alert-success'));
        return $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'websites','action'=>'contact'));
    }
    $this->Session->setFlash('Problem during sending email','default',array('class'=>'alert alert-warning'));
}
}
```

//contact.ctp

```
 <fieldset>
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->create('Website',array('controller'=>'websites','action'=>'contact_email'));
            echo $this->Form->input('useremail',array('class'=>'form-control'));
            echo $this->Form->input('usertopic',array('class'=>'form-control'));
            echo $this->Form->input('usermessage',array('class'=>'form-control'));
            echo $this->Form->submit('Send',array('class'=>'btn btn-default')); 
            echo $this->Form->end(); 
        ?>
    </fieldset>
```

all seems to be fine, even if statement in function contact_email is approved.

configuration ( i'm working on localhost, xampp, netbeans 7.4)

```
public $smtp = array(
    'transport' => 'Smtp',
    'from' => array('site@localhost' => 'My Site'),
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'port' => 25,
    'timeout' => 30,
    'username' => 'user',
    'password' => 'secret',
    'client' => null,
    'log' => false,
    //'charset' => 'utf-8',
    //'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
);
```

Comment: do you get the 'Mail sent' message or the 'Problem during sending email' message? Is your server configured to send email? Do you checked your spam email folder?

Comment: i'm getting "Mail sent" notification every time, I checked spam multiple times and nothing's here. And my configuration is on the bottom of the post

Comment: I don't see something like `$Email->config('smtp');` to tell cake to use that configuration array.

Comment: this conf file is located in app/config/email.php
i think there is no need to point that file

Comment: No, but it can contain many configuration arrays so you have to tell cake which array you want to use

Answer (score 2):

try this, you didn't set the config

```
public function contact_email()
{ /* all data is taken from contact.ctp, I debuged all data below and it's correct */
    $useremail = $this->data['Website']['useremail'];
    $usertopic = $this->data['Website']['usertopic'];
    $usermessage = $this->data['Website']['usermessage'];
    $Email = new CakeEmail();
    $Email->config('smtp')
          ->emailFormat('html')
          ->from($useremail)        
          ->to('wigan@mail.com')
          ->subject($usertopic); // all data is correct i checked several times
    if($Email->send($usermessage))
    {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Mail sent','default',array('class'=>'alert alert-success'));
        return $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'websites','action'=>'contact'));
    } else  {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Problem during sending email','default',array('class'=>'alert alert-warning'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the steps:

**step 1: In this file (app\Config\email.php)**
 add this:

```
public $gmail = array(
        'transport' => 'Smtp',
        'from' => array('site@localhost' => 'Any Text...'),
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
                'port' => 465,
        'timeout' => 30,
        'username' => 'youremail@example.com',
        'password' => 'yourPassword',
        'client' => null,
        'log' => false,
        //'charset' => 'utf-8',
        //'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
    );
```

**step 2: Add an email template (app\View\Emails\html\sample.ctp)**

```
<body>
<h1>Email Testing: <?php echo $first_name?></h1>
</body>
```

**step 3: Change the code in your method as shown below:**

```
public function send_my_email() {
        App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
        $Email = new CakeEmail();
        $Email->config('gmail'); //configuration
        $Email->emailFormat('html'); //email format
        $Email->to('receiveremail@ex.com');
        $Email->subject('Testing the emails');
        $Email->template('sample');//created in above step
        $Email->viewVars(array('first_name'=>'John Doe' ));//variable will be replaced from template
        if ($Email->send('Hi did you receive the mail')) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('Email successfully send on receiveremail@ex.com'));
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('Could not send the mail. Please try again'));
        }
    }
```