# Why gmail smtp doesn't work when sending mail in cakephp using localhost

Tags: email, cakephp

I get an error saying.

```
Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?
```

But yet I have enabled it in the php.ini file

Here is my EmailConfig

```
public $gmail = array(
            'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
            'port' => 465,
            'username' => 'email@gmail.com',
            'password' => 'password',
            'transport' => 'Smtp',
            'timeout' => 30,
    );
```

and my controller

```
public function send_mail(){
        $message = 'Test email';
        App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
        $email = new CakeEmail('gmail');
        $email->from('email@gmail.com');
        $email->to('email@yahoo.com');
        $email->subject('Test');
        $email->send($message);
    }
```

I fail to see where the problem lies

Comment: Make sure you enable php_openssl and php_opensockets incase if you haven't

Comment: Thank you @MiheretabAlemu, It was the opensocket extension that wasn't  enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
public function send_mail(){
        $message = 'Test email';
        App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
        $email = new CakeEmail();
        $email->config('gmail')
             ->from('email@gmail.com')
             ->to('email@yahoo.com')
             ->subject('Test')
             ->send($message);
    }
```

[I Want to send email from cakephp 2.x in company domain email adress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22552483/i-want-to-send-email-from-cakephp-2-x-in-company-domain-email-adress/22557309#22557309)

[CakePHP send email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20840249/cakephp-send-email/22557074#22557074)

Next step

> From wamp Apache/Apache_modules/ tick ssl_module

At the end

> Enable the php_openssl and php_opensockets

http://blog.techwheels.net/send-email-from-localhost-wamp-server-using-sendmail/

Comment: No luck, the changing of the syntax doesn't make a difference

Comment: Thank you for your efforts Mr @Isaac Rajaei, There was nothing wrong with the controller, It was the opensockets.dll that i havn't enabled. But it is fine now