# How to create a cron shell for sending email with cakephp 3.6

Tags: cakephp, cron, task, scheduled-tasks

I want cake to retrive for exemple a pdf invoice from a user and send email every 10 days

So as far as I understand for the sender
I made changement Inside

app.php

```
'EmailTransport' => [
    'default' => [
        'className' => 'Smtp',
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp-mail.outlook.com',
        'port' => 587,
        'timeout' => 30,
        'username' => exemple@live.fr,
        'password' => exemple,
        'client' => null,
        'tls' => yes,
        'url' => env('EMAIL_TRANSPORT_DEFAULT_URL', null),
```

Then I have to create the the Task Either Inside **src\console or src\shell** (not sure about thoses two)

Now do I have to create a Table email sql ? what changes to be applied for The UsersController

Exemple would Be appreciated 
Note : documentation didn't help at all

I tried this way but its outdated
[CakePHP send email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20840249/cakephp-send-email)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used PHPMailer library

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

And then followed this tutoriel now

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RzqfpT8gv0w&list=PLmrTMUhqzS3iwbxyd61TM4qxej4zfvKeo

now I'm able to send email with Cron Shell

Answer (score 1):

you should create inside **src\shell** and
format send mail

```
$email = new Email();
$email
    ->setEmailFormat('html')
    ->setTo($email)
    ->setFrom($your_email)
    ->setSubject($subject)
    ->send($content);
```